# condition does not recognize integers as number, it is considering it a character

Tags: r, character, numeric

I have a dataframe with 2 columns
The second column has one of the following values, recognized in the data frame as numbers: 0, 1, 2, or 3

I want to create a third column that has a character string values based on the values of the second column.

I tried:

```
df2 = data.frame(r = tssd2, cgmval = colcgm6)
df2$clrl[colcgm6 = 0] ="black"
df2$clrl[colcgm6 = 1] ="lightskyblue"
df2$clrl[colcgm6 = 2] ="blue"
df2$clrl[colcgm6 = 3] ="purple"
```

The error that I get is:

```
 Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "clrl", value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 4139
```

from the description of the error, my understanding is that the code is trying to compare the vaues of colcgm6 which are number (0 to 3) to characters 0, 1, 2, and 3. So the result is that the conditions are never true and no values are ever inputed into a new thir column.

Please help,

Edit:
For a reproducible example please use tssd as a vector of numeric values (1, 1, 1) and coldcgm6 as a vector of numeric values (0, 1, 2).

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Very sorry, I am new to both R and VBA Excel, and the concept of '==' was new to me and such a possibility didn't cross my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this easily by using numeric indexing instead of comparing (`==`) 4 times

```
clrl <- c("black", "lightskyblue", "blue", "purple")
df2$clrl <- clrl[colcgm6+1]
head(df2)
#           r cgmval         clrl
#1 -0.7622144      1 lightskyblue
#2 -1.4290903      0        black
#3  0.3322444      2         blue
#4 -0.4690607      2         blue
#5 -0.3349868      2         blue
#6  1.5362522      3       purple
```

---

In the OP's code, instead of using the logical operator (`==`), the assignment operator (`=`) is used.  By changing it, it would be fix the problem.

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
colcgm6 <- sample(0:3, 24, replace=TRUE)
tssd2 <- rnorm(24)
df2 <- data.frame(r = tssd2, cgmval = colcgm6)
```